# Submit not executed

Tags: forms

Why is my submit function never been executed?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function simpleexample_menu() {

  $items['simple-example-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Simple Multi-Step Form',
    'page callback' => 'create_request_custom',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function create_request_custom() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $form = node_add('request');

  $form['simpleexample'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => simpleexample_get_session(),
  );
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'create_request_custom_submit';

  return $form;
}

function create_request_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // never executing that
  $params = array(
    'nid' => $form_state['values']['nid'],
    'session_id' => $form_state['values']['simpleexample'],
  );
  .....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forms need to be called via [`drupal_get_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) that processes your $form array into a form. Including the submit handling. So it should look like more like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function simpleexample_menu() {

  $items['simple-example-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Simple Multi-Step Form',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', // Tell drupal to use the drupal_get_form function.
    'page arguments' => array('create_request_custom'), // Pass the form function as argument for the page callback.
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
```

Also you'll probably want to add the `$form` and `&$form_state` variables to the form function.

```
function create_request_custom($form, &$form_state) {
  // Your form function 
}
```